# How to install Keras and Tensorflow in Python 2.7.18?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have an assignment that I need to work with Python 2
and I also need Keras and Tensorflow. At which version should I downgrade
each package so I can install it in a Jupyter notebook or in Spyder 4.0.1 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try

```py
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

and

```py
pip install keras==2.2.4
```

Comment: I get the following errors when I am trying to pip install tensorflow 1.13.1                 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.1

Comment: then there must be list of version along with error, choose one of these

Comment: if these dont work, then you can do your assignment on Kaggle.com or colab.com. there python is already install, you can change version or install packages

Comment: This worked for me. And I had to add `pip install matplotlib==1.3.1`. (`pip install matplotlib` did not work in my case.)